# DFP non javascript version not counting impressions

Tags: javascript, html, ads, google-dfp

I'm having an issue with DFP where it is not counting the impressions or clicks of my ads when I use the non javascript version. The Javascript version works fine. I read something about having a pixel 1x1 but didn't quite get it.

Here's an example of an ad that prints correctly but never increases the impressions counter in DFP:

```
<a href="http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/jump?co=1&iu=/xxxxx/unit_001&sz=300x250&t=some%3Dthing&c=%recipient.timestamp%">
  <img src="http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ad?co=1&iu=/xxxxx/unit_001&sz=300x250&t=some%3Dthing&c=%recipient.timestamp%">
</a>
```

I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also posted this issue to the DFP forum and an expert got back to me saying that basically it cannot be done the way I wanted to get the total of impressions for each add that gets displayed through the non-javascript tags. However, there's a "workaround" where you can get a report of all the times the ad has been served.

In order to get this report, you have to go to the left side of your DFP account and click under the "Queries" option. Then create a new query and make sure you select the option "Total code served count" under the **Metrics** section.

In case you want to look into the original thread on the DFP forum, please go to https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/dfp/p5zdvXvyxjg;context-place=forum/dfp

I hope this helps someone else.